# VBA Open workbook from current cells value

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have a spreadsheet which I want to use the current cells value to open the url specified there and enter into the column next to it. The URL only contains one set of characters. I tried recording with relative references turned on and got the following:

```
Sub GETASINV2()
'
' GETASINV2 Macro
'

'
    Selection.Copy
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="http://upctoasin.com/027616716927", Origin:= _
        xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote _
        , ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:= _
        False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

As you can see it all seems to be relative apart from the filename where it has picked up the value I entered and not the fact that I "copy pasted the value".

Once this is done I want to repeat for the remaining list of urls (around 3000). I can probably find someway of repeating till no more URLS exist but if you know a way would be glad to get help on this part also!

Thank you

Comment: What does the cell value look like? Is it this part, `027616716927`? Also, check out [how to avoid using `.Select`/`.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros), and try and use the data directly.

Comment: Hello the cell value is http://upctoasin.com/027616716927 (with the http), will read up on the select activate also.

Answer (score 0):

I put the link you gave us in rows `A1:A10` and ran the following code to get loop through each cell and place the value from the link in the cell to it's right.

*I also tested it with 1000 links and it completed in 279 seconds -- so roughly 4 per second. I'd be interested to see if anyone has a quicker method.*

```
Sub GETASINV2()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'update for your worksheet name

    Dim inputRange As Range, r As Range
    Set inputRange = sht.Range("A1:A10") 'update for your range

    For Each r In inputRange
        With sht.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "URL;" & r.Value, Destination:=r.Offset(0, 1))
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            .Delete
        End With
    Next r

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

**Update**

> Is there a way of it working out the size of the range itself based on the number of records without a gap?

Yes, you can replace this:

```
Set inputRange = sht.Range("A1:A10")
```

With the following:

```
Set inputRange = Range(sht.Range("A1"), sht.Range("A1").End(xlDown))
```

Where `A1` is the location of your first link

Comment: This is working flawlessly thank you! Is there a way of it working out the size of the range itself based on the number of records without a gap?

Comment: Happy to help :). I've updated my answer for your comment/ question. If you find this answers your question please *accept* by clicking the green tick mark to the left of this answer